# Modification of a read-only value attempted

Tags: perl

I've googled the error (stated in the Question title) and can't find anything relevant.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %cc;

my @cc => (3,4,5,6,6,7,7);
$cc{key} = \@cc;

$0 =  $cc{key}[0] * 2;
$1 =  $cc{key}[1] * 1;  #error here

my $total = $0 + $1;

print "$1";
print "$total";
```

line 11 is my error...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$0` and `$1` are special variables in Perl (see [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)).  `$1` is a read only variable.

Also, you should enable [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) to see many more problems with your code.

My guess is that you want something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @cc = (3,4,5,6,6,7,7);
my %cc;
$cc{key} = \@cc;

my $k0 = $cc{key}[0] * 2;
my $k1 = $cc{key}[1] * 1;
my $total = $k0 + $k1;

print "$k1\n";
print "$total\n";
```

[perldoc perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) has more information on the error message: "Modification of a read-only value attempted".